# Question regarding bandwidth of digitally modulated signals

Tags: wireless, digital-communications, bandwidth

Assume that there are two carrier frequencies, 20 GHz (RF) and 200 THz (Optical). Both of these carrier waves are modulated by a digital signal using QPSK scheme.

Consider the frequency spectrum (or Power spectral density) of both the modulated waves. If we were to consider the bandwidth of their power spectra, will the modulated wave with the higher carrier frequency of 200 THz occupy more bandwidth and hence delivers a higher data rate (Shannon-Hartley theorem)?
I'm asking this because I'm confused whether bandwidth or the carrier frequency affects the bit rate. Shannon-Hartley theorem says that higher the bandwidth, more the bit rate. So, does that mean, as we go to higher carrier frequencies, bandwidth will be higher since we are switching at a higher speed?
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *If we were to consider the bandwidth of their power spectra, will the
> modulated wave with the higher carrier frequency of 200 THz occupy
> more bandwidth and hence delivers a higher data rate (Shannon-Hartley
> theorem)?*

If both carriers are modulated the same way with the same data, then their bandwidth occupancies will be identical.

> *I'm asking this because I'm confused whether bandwidth or the carrier
> frequency affects the bit rate.*

It's available bandwidth that determines the digital data rate.

> *So, does that mean, as we go to higher carrier frequencies, bandwidth
> will be higher since we are switching at a higher speed?*

No, the bandwidth of the modulated carrier will be the same in both cases.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Since the optical channel has more available bandwidth, why doesn't it provide a better data rate. The whole reason we are switching to optical fibre is for better data rates. So, shouldn't the QPSK signal with 200 THz have higher bandwidth?
What am I missing here?

Comment: It *could* provide a better data rate but it's the modulation method that limits the true data rate AND the amount of background noise. The modulation method produces the same width and shape of spectra at 20 MHz, 20 GHz or whatever. Apart from anything else, when you modulate light, you will be superimposing a much lower carrier frequency that can be modulated by QPSK because, there are no commercial methods of applying QPSK directly to light frequencies.

Comment: Okay, got it.
So, how do we increase the bit rate then (Assuming some other modulation) using the optical carrier? Should we switch the digital data at higher rates to achieve the same?
Sorry if I'm asking too many questions, its not yet clear to me. :(

Comment: This is a Q and A site and not a progressive learning environment, talking shop or forum. I'm saying this because you are straying away from your original question significantly when you ask "how to do this". So, I don't believe you are modulating the optical light frequencies; you might be modulating at a frequency in the high MHz or low GHz range and, to increase data rate you need to look to your modulation circuit and see if it can be driven at a higher data rate. Bear in mind what I said at the start of this comment.

Comment: @Girishkarthik OK, that's good. You should take the [2 minute tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand the motivation for folk giving free answers and how to close down this session.